# Magento 2 Minicart and Gallery Image slow

Tags: magento2

Not sure if it is only my problem. If i go to any product page until the gallery image loaded for the product mini cart never loaded. is there any idea how can i speed up this? as my site is very fast except this two things.

https://www.banglashoppers.com/ofra-perfecting-puff-beauty-blender.html

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I have noticed this getting worse on some computers until a full cache flush is done on client PC's seems to be knockout takes an age to populate the minicart and then gallery does not load until this is complete. This speeds up dramatically after a cache flush from what I can tell however. Did you have any luck with this?

Answer (score 1):

I understand your issue as being that the "number" in the minicart only loads after the page gallery images have loaded.

I can confirm the same behavor on my Magento 2.2.0 installation. The number of items loads at the last moment.

Besides that, I think you have some optimization to do. From central Europe, your site doesn't load fast and the pagespeed ranking is poor. Have a look at Google [PageSpeed insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.banglashoppers.com%2Fofra-perfecting-puff-beauty-blender.html). Some ideas, turn on the cache, optimize your images, turn on bundling / minifying of JS and CSS (please be aware, it may break your site depending on which magento 2 version you run). You could also install the mod_pagespeed, and elaborate with their filters.